# WCFUserEventProvider blank E2EActivityId

Tags: c#, wcf, appfabric

I am using the WCFUserEventProvider code ([as specified here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/06/09/tracking-wcf-data-services-with-windows-server-appfabric.aspx)) to log some events from my wcf service.

Even though the monitoring level is set to End to end, the user defined events that i am writing are all having a blank  (000-000-0000....) E2EActivtiyId.

Is it possible to log these events in appfabric monitoring with the same E2EactivitiyId as the events logged by WCF infrastructure ?

Comment: I had the same issue, I finally solved it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848552/eventprovider-activityid-in-a-call-context-using-appfabric/14834007#14834007

Answer (score 0):

just in case someone runs into this, this can be done by setting CorrelationManager's ActivityId value at the first message inspector you encounter.

Comment: By CorrelationManager do you mean to set Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId?